# Google Cloud Platform Android example app not working on real device

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I'm trying to run the Google Cloud Platform Android app example, it' s a cloud [guestbook app.](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/android)

Later in the tutorial, it uses the Google Cloud Messaging to live update the guestbook as new messages comes.

So i runned a new emulator with Google and try the app to see if it works.

When i write a message on my real device, the emulator get update in few seconds, But when i write a message on the emulator the real device don't get update at all.

My real device run android 4.4.2 but it's a custom rom.

Here a screen when i run the app:
[image]

I think that the yellow triangle inside the Target means something, but i'm not sure of it because the Google Cloud Messaging should ever works, i mean, how can i use Whatsapp and similar apps?

Thanks for help!

Comment: As it's a custom ROM, I assume it doesn't have the Google APIs built in, hence the yellow warning and failure of GCM.

Comment: Uhm ok but how can apps like whatsapp run on my device then? Also please post your comment as an answer so i can accept it :)

Comment: Also i'm not sure about that. I mean i installed the google package so i have playstore and other google apps